# Issues using 'sed' in a bash script

Tags: bash, sed

macOS

Hello, I would need some help please :

I'm using sed via that command line in a bash script :

```
sed -i '' ' PrimaryGenerator/EnergySampler/Fixed/Energy s 90.000000 0.0' benchmark_cube_saphir_attenuation.txt
```

My idea is to change 90.0 for 0.0 whether my line contains "PrimaryGenerator/EnergySampler/Fixed/Energy".
And I get :

```
sed: 1: " PrimaryGenerator/Energ ...": extra characters at the end of P command
```

I searched a bit but I give up, did I wrote something wrong please ?
Thanks.

Comment: Could you please explain more what you are trying to achieve here? try adding samples of input and expected output into your question for better understanding of question, thank you.

Comment: In sed, every instruction starts with an optional address or address range, followed by a command. You didn't give either.

Comment: RavinderSingh13, thanks for the answer, well it works with the reply of choroba just below. But I'll keep in mind to display examples in my future questions !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using an alternate address delimiter, the first delimiter must be backslashed.

Whatever separator you use in the substitution, you can't omit the closing one.

```
sed '\ PrimaryGenerator/EnergySampler/Fixed/Energy s 90.000000 0.0 '
#    ~                                                            ~
```

Also note that the dot in `90.000000` matches any character.